# MuleSoft - How to validate the existence of a field in a JSON?

Tags: validation, mule, dataweave

I have a component which gets JSON input, e.g.

```
{
  "a": "value",
  "b": null
}
```

I want to validate that b appears, though it can be null. So the above should pass the validation, but the following should not:

```
{
  "a": "value"
}
```

How can I do this with MuleSoft? I only found the "is not null" validation, but there doesn't seem to be any "exists" validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a DataWeave expression you can use the [key present selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors).

Example:
`payload.b?`

If you use the Validation Module you can use that expression for an Is True `<validation:is-true>` validation operation.